# DENY statement in Teradata

Tags: teradata

I created a table in the database DB1. There are other users with the same permission (role ROLE1). The only permission I have is via a role, say named ROLE1: U, D, CT, I, DV, R, DT, CG, R, CV on DB1. I am now the creator of this table, and I can do all DDL/DML with it. I want to remove DELETE/INSERT access from the other members of ROLE1 (or from individual users), is this possible? DENY statement is not available, and REVOKE only revokes my GRANTs. I don't have any control on ROLE1. Thanks

Comment: If there's a right on database level, there's no way to restrict rights on a individual object. If this is a sandbox database the DBAs should grant only CREATE TABLE rights, then each table can be accessed by it's creator only (who could grant rights to other users, too)

Comment: Thanks for the response @dnoeth. Can the creator grant access to other users who don't have any access on this database (they have access to other databases)?

Comment: Of course, the creator gets all rights including GRANT OPTION